# How to perform the same query on multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, business-objects, postgresql-9.6

I'd like to audit specific user activity across our application's database. Most of the important tables have these metadata fields:

- id
- date_last_edited
- last_edited_by

I've got a prototype working:

```sql
with "params" as (
    select
        'DeethJ' as user,
        '2022-09-01' as from_date,
        '2022-09-30' as to_date
)

select 'address' as "table", id, date_last_edited, last_edited_by
from address
join params
    on last_edited_by = params.user
    and date_last_edited between params.from_date and params.to_date

union

select 'person' as "table", id, date_last_edited, last_edited_by
from person
join params
    on last_edited_by = params.user
    and date_last_edited between params.from_date and params.to_date

union

select 'person_person_relationship' as "table", id, date_last_edited, last_edited_by
from person_person_relationship
join params
    on last_edited_by = params.user
    and date_last_edited between params.from_date and params.to_date
```

Is there a way I can provide a list of table names and do the same query on each one - some kind of `union_agg` function?

Constraints: the database is PostgreSQL 9.6 (yes, I know, they said they will update it), my access is the "Freehand SQL data source" within SAP BusinessObjects so I can only provide a single statement. I cannot create a function or procedure.

Prospects look dim so I might instead generate the query in Excel...

Comment: No, you have to spell it out. You can write client code to construct the `UNION` for you.

Comment: Generating the query from the same spreadsheet I maintain to annotate the schema worked surprisingly painlessly.